# How come afterCommandExec doesn't fire in CKEditor 4?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I took a look at the CKEditor API and found this useful event:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-afterCommandExec

It's not working for anything that requires a dropdown ( classname, font, fontsize ) but it works for any buttons like bold, link, undo.

Does anyone have any ideas why this doesn't work or if there is some other event for these kind of toolbar plugins?

Comment: I looked into the instance via Firebug and see font isn't part of its "commands" property so I guess that's why it doesn't work but now I'm hunting for a way to know when richcombos change value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because these dropdowns (font size/family, format, etc) don't use commands.

I think that you can use [selectionChange](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-selectionChange) event. It's fired every time selection's [elementPath](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath) is modified (including focus/blur). So all buttons, every dropdown fire this even when clicked.

Comment: I looked into that but I don't see a way to get the value of the font when it's changed... I inspected the object but couldn't find anything of use

Comment: Could you describe more precisely what you're trying to achieve? Something like recording all changes done by the user?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back. I have web fonts and typekit fonts. I need to know if the user selects a typekit font to do special behaviors. Right now I'm getting around by using saveSnapshot event and looking at DOM label to figure what font is used which I'm not too happy about

Comment: In this case you have to listen on some generic events and check DOM. Only this way you'll be able to handle undo, paste, all ways of changing font-family (including combos and source mode) and inserting content. I recommend you `selectionChange` and `dataReady` - these two should be enough.